# Using scientific notation in pandas

Tags: numpy, pandas, formatting

I found plenty of answers on how to suppress scientific notation in pandas, but how do I *enable* it? I found the option `pd.set_option('precision', 2)` but it does not turn large numbers into scientific notation.

For example, I would like the number `123066.14` to be formatted as `1.23E+5`. I am using a `pandas.DataFrame`, and it would be useful to set the formatting for an entire column when exporting/printing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK, I figured this out, you can use [`set_option`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html#pandas.set_option) and pass a format string to option `'display.float_format'`:

```
In [76]:
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2g}'.format)

In [78]:
pd.Series(data=[0.00000001])

Out[78]:
0   1e-08
dtype: float64
```

**EDIT**

to match your desired output:

```
In [79]:
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2E}'.format)
pd.Series(data=[0.00000001])

Out[79]:
0   1.00E-08
dtype: float64
```

Comment: By the way, I found `:.2E` to be a better formatting. It uses a capital `E` while also ensuring 2 digits after the decimal point. The `g` mode will hide the second `0`.

Comment: for whatever reason e/E keeps 1 more digit than g/G. The capitalization of e and g selects whether the output uses small `e` or big `E`.