# type switch from int to float64 after merge creating error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to merge two dataframes in Pandas. One of the dataframes has a numerical column whose type is "int64"

However, after the merge, the type is switched to "float64" for some reason.  Note that this is not my join column

When I try to access the dataframe, it errors out:

In [56]: account_aggregates.head()
Out[56]: ) failed: TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not numpy.float64>

Comment: Can you post the output from `df.info()` from both dfs and the merged one, what may have happened is that you have missing values which will change the dtype to float due to the presence of `NaN`, also regarding that error, check your `pd.set_options` in particular `'display.float_format'`

Comment: @EdChum it was the display.float_format that was causing the problem.  Once I reset it, output was fine. Why does missing values change the dtype to float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the dtype is changed to `float64` is because missing values `NaN` cannot be represented using integer.

With respect to the error message, I had a hunch that it was `'display.float_format'` as I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983341/using-scientific-notation-in-pandas/31983844#31983844) earlier today on this and saw this error. I think that it's because you have to pass a `str.format` as the value rather than a format string:

`pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2g}'.format)` as opposed to `pd.set_option('display.float_format', '%.2g')` as an example.