# scientific notation in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two CSV files both files when I read an print the files the output is like:

```
tweet_id                    id        
312498024964313000          3.430000e+17     
312278640362659000          3.430000e+17
```

The id and tweet_id both columns are in the same format and required sample output is :

```
tweet_id              id        
3.124980e+17          3.430660e+17 
3.122790e+17          3.430880e+17
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.
I later use both of these columns to merge two CSV files.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using scientific notation in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983341/using-scientific-notation-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `float_format` with `pd.set_option`.  Just change both columns to `float` first:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.6g}'.format)

df.astype(float)
     tweet_id  id        
0 3.12498e+17    3.43e+17
1 3.12279e+17    3.43e+17
```

Note: Your expected output for `id` doesn't seem to match your input.  The above result is based on the sample input provided.

Comment: return the same

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you have to combine them into 1 data frame. You can tell because your printed statement on the bottom starts at a 0 index as well.

Use the .join method to join them, then try print them:

```
data_frame1 = pd.DataFrame(data=['a','b', 'c'], columns=['Alphabit'])
data_frame2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3], columns = ['Numbers'])
data_frame1.join(data_frame2)
```

edit: sorry I think i misinterpreted your original question.

Comment: The problem is when I try to join them it returns me null values. As id and tweet_id locations are not the same.